# 2 Wordpress Installation 1 DB (sort of)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a admin page on a different sub domain.

e.g Main website - www.mydomain.com
Admin Website - admin.mydomain.com

Both websites have completely different themes because Admin Website will be running a customise theme, and will have additional backend features like accounting/CRM etc.

I'm currently running on 2 installations of wordpress and 2 databases. Main website is running a Reviews function and a Private Message function that allows me to write a review for a user, and send private message to user.

I log all reviews and private message in Main Website Database by using $wpdb->Insert

However, now, i want to let all these reviews and private message to be available to my user, and I want to let Admin Website and Main Website share same USER database (for the convenience of login and log out), because on the Admin website the user can change his personal information etc which will be reflected in the Main Website.

TLDR Version: How do I use 1 database for 2 installations and let both access get_post, get_usermeta, get_postmeta etc in their own installation?

I understand if share database i will have problem with the hyperlinks etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create install WordPress multi sites and here is the link below,
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: thank u, exactly what i'm doing now. and hopefully i can resolve all the users sync issue with wordpress multisite now.